# Defining the Name of a control in a Template in a subsequent event

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I am trying to access the WebBrowser "wb" in the Img_ToolKitOpening event but it cannot be found.
Wb is defined in a Template

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border  x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"  Background="#EEFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC"  RenderTransformOrigin="1,1" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>

                           <Image x:Name="img" ToolTipService.Placement="Top"
                            Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" Height="64" 
                             Stretch="Fill" Width="64" ToolTipOpening="img_ToolTipOpening">
                                <Image.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" x:Name="scaleTrans"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Image.RenderTransform>
                                <Image.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Effect="{x:Null}"
                                             DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" 
                                             HasDropShadow="False">
                                        <Border Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="160" Margin="0" Width="100" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
                                                <WebBrowser x:Name="wb"  
                                                 Width="600" Height="600"   />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </Image.ToolTip>
                            </Image> 
                        </Grid>
                      </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>


</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbMovies" Height="92" Margin="81,0,94,26" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

I am hoping to be able to perform wb.Navigate(@"c:\dump\bb.htm") to define the
HTML page to be displayed in the ToolTip when it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Ifits defined in a template you could try to bind to the Source and then the event when the source is updated, if you cannot manage to access the WB in the codebehind.

```
Source="{Binding Path=WebBrowserUri}" SourceUpdated="wb_SourceUpdated"
```